New out-of-the-box tab component
I am changing my Community pages from using the deprecated tab component to the "new" tab component.  I cannot figure out how to apply the same CSS I have on the old tab component to the new one.  The Salesforce instructions say "If you applied custom CSS to the Tabs component, it doesn’t automatically apply to the new Tab Layout component. Adjust the custom CSS so that it points to the correct new CSS selector."  I need direction on where to do this.  I don't see a reference to tabs in the override CSS at the Community level.
Here is the old look:

Here is the new look:

You can edit the question and add the code for the tab and CSS.
